# common parser for solr response

Tags: solr

In solr, i am searching simultaneously in database, xml files, pdfs etc. so the solr search response have different fields for each search result record (for each document or database record).

Here how can i write the common response parser to parse the different fields(ie My PDF have different fields , database tables have different fields)

Comment: what language do you use? You should add more details what you want todo. E.g. in RoR I use acts_as_solr and there I easy get all models into one index and decide what I want to get with a multi model search on SOLR

Comment: I am using java. Here i am indexing the PDF files , database tables etc. All having different fields such as table having firstname,lastname and PDF files having content field. So after i did the search i am getting the response as a XML format . Here how can i write the common parser to parse the response independent of the field names and showing to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to doing this is to try to have one uniform datamodel. Try to first identity what you want to show your users. For example if you run a library you might have fields such as:

- ISBN (String, single value, unique as id)
- Title (Text field)
- Author (Multi valued text field) Cost  (Int, single value)

Then try to map all your datasources to populate these fields.  Either you map this datamodel in your “connectors” (custom code extracting the data) or you to look at copy fields for doing this. See link:

[Solr copy fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)

Comment: Oh, and of course Solr is built to have a "sparse" datamodel, so each data source does of course not have to populate all fields.